# Todolist with mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I've just created a todo list html page which links to do the database containing id itemname and done. I am trying to link the id of this table to the id of the login table, which contains id, username and password. I can pass the username to the home page when the user logs in, but how can I link the same id of the user with the id when creating an item in the todo list? this is my code
validation.php

```
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];



$s = " select * from usertable1 where username = '$username' ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$error = "username/password incorrect";

if($num == 1 ){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
        $_SESSION['username']= $username;
        header('location:home.php');
    }else{

        header("location: index.php");
    }

}else{
    header("location: index.php");

}



 ?>
```

todolist.php

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';

$itemsQuery = $db ->prepare("
SELECT id, name, done
FROM items
WHERE username = :username
");
$itemsQuery->execute([
  'username'=>$_SESSION ['id']
]);
$items = $itemsQuery->rowCount()? $itemsQuery :[];
foreach ($items as $items ) {
  echo $item['name'], '<br>';
}
 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
   <meeta charset = "utf-8">
   <title> To do</title>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel ="stylesheet" href="cool.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1.0:>

 </head>
<body>
  <div class ="list">
    <h1 class ="header"> To do.</h1>

    <?php if(!empty($items)):
      ?>
    <ul class="items
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <li>
          <span class="item<?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : ''?>"><?php echo $item['name'];?></span>
          <?php if(!$item['done']): ?>
          <a href="mark.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item['id'];?>" class="done-button"> Mark as done</a>
          <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    </<?php else: ?>
      <p> You haven't added any items yet. </php>
        </<?php endif; ?>

    <form class="item-add" action="add.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type a new item here." class="input" autocomplete="off" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">

    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

init.php

```
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];
$s = " select * from usertable where username = '$username' ";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $s);


if($num == 1){
  $_SESSION['username']= $username;
}else{
  die('You are not signed in.');
}

 ?>
```

Comment: You store the id in the session, and that's how you 1. check whether anyone is logged in and 2. identify *who* is logged in…?!

Comment: do I need to link the id from item table to the id of user table? with a foreign key?

Comment: Probably yes. Each item belongs to a user, so you have a `user_id` column in your `items` table.

Comment: @Werokk can you post the database table structure ? so proper suggestion can be given

Comment: @Werokk in my opinion you have to read the `Relationship` topic in RDBMS

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi so in my item table I have : id(primary key), name, user, done(when the done button is clicked) , created(gets the date) and on my user table I have id(primary key) username, password

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi I know, I haven't done it for a while, but i have a deadline to meet in 4 hours, that's why I am asking help here

Comment: @Werokk  yes if `item` is added by `user` then you have to keep the track of `user id` form the `user table` to `item table's` `user` filed.  short answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some extra thought from my mind.**

> **item table:** id(primary key), name, user, done(when the done button is clicked) , created(gets the date)

---

> **user table:**  id(primary key) username, password

**First Approach:**

when user create/add a new item then user's `id` from the `user` table also get stored into the `item` table's `user` field.

so for this you can keep logged user's details like `id` into the `session` after successful login.

---

**Second Approach:** 
here you will create another table which contains the relationship in between 
`item` and `user` table

> **item_to_user_table:** id, item_id(id of the newly added item from item table),user_id(id of the user form session or `user` table)

so when user create/add new item then  following process goes

1. inser new item into the `item` table
2. just after the insert new item use [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) function to get the last `inserted id` of item
3. then use step 2 `inserted_id` and `user_id` into the third table `item_to_user_table`

**Pro of second method:** `item` and relationship details will be stored separately so later on you can easily delete the item from `item table` without affecting the `user table`

**Cons:** lengthy and need some extra hard work.